# Handling Zero Count in Extension Function - for result in image.results

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, nsimage

I have an extension for NSImage that does a computationally intensive process.It is called by

```
image.results
```

Im iterating through the results like

```
for result in image.results
```

I need to check if the result count is zero and do something

It seems that I need to call the function again to get the result count

```
image.results.count
```

This would be wasting computation time.How can I get around this,Please advice.

Comment: Call it once and assign the result to a variable? `let results = image.results`

Comment: @MartinR Thanks.. Should I dispose off the variable explicitly ? I'm currently using `autoreleasepool {`

Comment: There is not enough information given to answer that question.

Comment: @MartinR There is the Main Loop in which I'm doing this computationally intensive task and it uses an autorelease pool like this  `for x in fileArray  { autoreleasepool {` .If I declare temporary variable like you have stated in the sub loop ,will this be automatically disposed off? In C# for Bitmap,we need to call `bitmap.dispose()` to explicitly dispose the bitmap.Is the same applicable for SWIFT?

Comment: @MartinR Can you please advice me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904176/dismissing-view-controller-not-stopping-async-task/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable and assign the result to it and if you need to access it from more than one place create a singleton class, with a variable for your `results` and assign it to it:

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    var results = [NSImage]()
}
```

Assign it:

```
Singleton.sharedInstance.results = image.results
```

To read from it from whatever controller:

```
let count = Singleton.sharedInstance.results.count
```

Comment: Thanks.. Should I dispose off the variable explicitly ? I'm currently using `autoreleasepool {`

Comment: No I don´t think it´s necessary to do that.

Comment: @techno btw don't check `if  image.results.count == 0` check if your array `image.results.isEmpty`

Comment: @LeoDabus Im using `image.results.count==0`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the in-depth information :) .. will change my code.

Comment: @LeoDabus Is the SWIFT Compiled Executable on OSX in Machine Language..? Is easy disassembly possible?

Comment: @LeoDabus Please advice me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904176/dismissing-view-controller-not-stopping-async-task/